# Unable to reverse a String after converting it to String Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string

I am trying to convert a `String` to a `String Array` using the `split` method. When I try to individually reverse elements of the array using the `reverse` method, the `reverse` method doesn't even show up in Eclipse Code Suggestions. Explicitly using `reverse`, spurts out an error saying `The method reverse() is undefined for the type String`.
Please help!

```
public class Split {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String temp;

        String names="Apple Banana Cabbage Daffodil";

        String[] words = names.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

            temp = words[i].reverse();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You want `Daffodil Cabbage Banana Apple` as output or to reverse each word ??

Comment: @Junaid,He is splitting first before reverse.

Comment: `The method reverse() is undefined for the type String` - That's an informative error message right there.

Comment: Your code is trying to reverse the elements of the String object, which are the character it is composed of. The method `reverse()` is not a method in the Spring API. You have to call `reverse()` in your `Collections` object, not the `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler message is clear: `reverse` is not a method of `String`.

Try:

```
String reverse = new StringBuilder(words[i]).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method reverse for type String but you could do it yourself like:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

            String temp;

            String names="Apple Banana Cabbage Daffodil";

            String[] words = names.split(" ");
            String[] reverseWords = new String[words.length];
            int counter = words.length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                reverseWords[counter] = new String(words[i]);
                counter--;
            }
            words = reverseWords;
            for(String i : words)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + i);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `reverse` method defined for the `String` type. You can use [`Collections#reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) on a `List` which reverses its elements:

```
String[] words = names.split(" ");

List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
Collections.reverse(wordList);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because String doesn't have method **reverse**, you can use **StringBuilder** instead.

Like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String temp;

    String names = "Apple Banana Cabbage Daffodil";

    String[] words = names.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        temp = new StringBuilder(words[i]).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```